# I'm trying to scrape data into an .xls file with xlsxwriter but the data its self writes to the sheet 5 times instead of just once

Tags: python, excel, xpath, web-scraping, xlsxwriter

I'm able to write to an excel sheet the important data I need from my webpage, but it writes to it 6 times before it moves on to the next Ticker symbol in my "Tickers.csv" loop.

Values[0]<==(numbers) is the data that writes 5 times and I'm not sure why. Values2[0]<==(letters) only writes once, which is what I would expect values[0] to do as well.

Example,

Values2[0] = Apple Inc, AAPL

Values[0] = 123
123
123
123
123
123

> Values[0] should equal this in my train of thought:
>
> Values[0] = 123

My code writes this in spreadsheet:

Apple Inc, AAPL

123

123

123

123

123

123

International Business Machines, IBM

456

456

456

456

456

456

I would like the sheet to turn out like this and don't understand why it isn't:,

Apple Inc, AAPL

123

International Business Machines, IBM

456

I'm using XPath to scrape the data into the sheet so the only way that I know of to get it on to the sheet is to add an index (i.e. values[0] instead of just values). When I don't add an index I receive an error stating that I'm not allowed to write lists.

If you need more information on my situation just ask and thank you for your time.

def main():
                    import csv
                    import os
                    from selenium import webdriver
                    from selenium import webdriver

```
                chrome_path = r"C:\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe"
                browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)


                stocks_arr =[]
                pfolio_file = open("tickers.csv", "r")
                for line in pfolio_file:
                    indv_stock_arr = line.strip().split(",")
                    stocks_arr.append(indv_stock_arr)

                stock_info_arr = []

                for stock in stocks_arr:
                    stock_info = []
                    ticker = stock[0]
                    stock_info.append(ticker)

                    url="https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{0}?p={0}&.tsrc=fin-srch".format(ticker)

                    browser.get(url)

                    try:
                        values_elementticker = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='D(ib) ']")

                        values2 = [x.text for x in values_elementticker]
                        print(values2[0])
                    except IndexError:
                            with open("results2.xls", "a") as f:
                                for i in range(len(values2)):
                                    f.write(values2[0] + "\n")
                    try:    
                        values_element = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='Trsdu(0.3s) ']")
                        values = [x.text for x in values_element]
                        print(values[0])
                    except IndexError:
                            with open("results2.xls", "a") as f:
                                    f.write("-" + "\n")     
                    with open("results2.xls", "a") as f:
                        for i in range(len(values2)):
                            f.write(values2[0] + "\n")  
                        for i in range(len(values)):
                            f.write(values[0] + "\n")       
                print("Script completed")

                browser.close()
                restart = input("Do you wish to start again?").lower()
                if restart == "yes":
                    main()

                else:
                    exit()
            main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You launch a for loop with the range of the 'values' list.

And writing not a new value every time (like: values[i]), but every time the same first element: values[0]

If you need just one element, no need of loop...

so hide the loop, change the lines:

```
for i in range(len(values)):
                f.write(values[0] + "\n")
```

to:

```
#for i in range(len(values)):
f.write(values[0] + "\n")
```